# v-model issue on a nested object property that may not exist

Tags: json, vue.js

I have this working, but I would like to find a way to handle any level of nesting with v-model or something re-usable rather than creating companion functions every time.

```
      <select :value="task.settings && task.settings.task_type ? task.settings.task_type : ''"
              @input="e => setSetting('task_type', e.target.value)">
        <option value="">Select Task Type</option>
        <option>Habit</option>
        <option>Appointment</option>
        <option>Recurring</option>
        <option>Meeting</option>
      </select>
```

And in methods:

```
setSetting(key, value) {
  this.task.settings[key] = value
},
```

Comment: I think that you must ensure that the object property used as `v-model` already exists in the target object. If it does not exist - Vue will not try to create the whole path to this property, it will only create the property if the parent object already exists. I.e. you can set `v-model="object.property"` and it will work if the `property` is absent initially but `object` exists. However, `v-model="obj_1.obj_2.obj_3.property` will not work if `obj_3` does not exist initially.

Comment: Thanks, so no shortcuts? I guess that makes sense. I was hoping for something more elegant.